# Connect to a remote mysql server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP version 5.3.2 installed. I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql database version 4.1.22

The PHP is running on IIS7

The problem is in my php.ini, only 2 files are included as extensions:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

I added these to the php.ini

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and also placed the 3 dll files in the ext folder where PHP is installed.
But I keep getting a 500 server error. Nothing is recorded in the PHP error log.

I got this from the event viewer application error:

```
Faulting application php-cgi.exe, version 5.3.2.0, time stamp 0x4b8ebb1d, faulting module php-cgi.exe, version 5.3.2.0, time stamp 0x4b8ebb1d, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000193a, process id 0x2540, application start time 0x01cd441011e2e3a0.
```

Basically I'm getting an error on using the mysql_connect() which is:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: while you have PDO available , you still insist on using `mysql_*` functions ? **WHY ?!** Also, the cause of problem is messed up installation/config of php. Most likely the DLLs are at fault.

Comment: @teresko: Its some legacy code, I cannot change the code. Lots of it. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application pool is set to the correct 32-bit/64-bit mode

Answer (score 0):

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Makes it quite clear: php_mysql extension hasn't been loaded.

First of all make sure your php installation uses the php.ini file you have edited. Create a php file containing

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

open it in browser and in output check php_ini path. If it's correct have a look at extensions directory and see if it matches the location you have placed the dlls in.

Comment: I did all that before posting this comment. The thing is, when I include those 3 mysql DLLs, I start getting that 500 server error and the event viewer log that I've posted in the main post.

Comment: Are you 100% sure those dlls are getting loaded? Does anything mysql-related show in phpinfo output? Have you tried loading just php_mysqli.dll or just php_mysql.dll without the other two?